# Numerous Extraneous Error Messages from EvaluationData

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, message-coding

In the course of solving question [134644](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134660/1063), I encountered the message

> > Reduce::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity -Log[5381171456512]+Log[(-Sqrt[101] Log[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96390/1063)-10 Sqrt[101] Log[5]+101 (Log[<<1>>]+<<1>>+<<1>>)+Sqrt[101] Log[Plus[<<2>>]])^10/((30100251-2278951 Sqrt[101]) (Log[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96390/1063)+10 Log[5]-Log[Plus[<<2>>]])^10)] is equal to zero. Assuming it is.

with the numeric quantity in `Short` form.  To obtain the entire expression, I tried

```
EvaluationData[Reduce[eq3 /. {m -> 0, n -> 0}, {A, c1, d, k}, Reals]]
```

along the line of an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96390/1063) by Szabolcs.  Indeed, it provided the desired complete expression.  But, it also provided about 125 error messages, all apparently internally generated by `EvaluationData`.  Although the desired quantity can be isolated by

```
EvaluationData[Reduce[eq3 /. {m -> 0, n -> 0}, {A, c1, d, k}, Reals]]
    ["MessagesExpressions"][[-1, 1, 2]] // ReleaseHold
(* -Log[5381171456512] + Log[(-Sqrt[101] Log[2] - 10 Sqrt[101] Log[5] + 
   101 (Log[2] + 10 Log[5] - Log[30100251 - 2278951 Sqrt[101]]) + 
   Sqrt[101] Log[30100251 - 2278951 Sqrt[101]])^10/((30100251 - 2278951 Sqrt[101]) 
   (Log[2] + 10 Log[5] - Log[30100251 - 2278951 Sqrt[101]])^10)] *)
```

I do not find this work-around particularly satisfying.  Two questions:

1. Is this undesired `EvaluationData` behavior a bug?  (I believe it is.)
2. Does an alternative work-around exist, perhaps by instructing `Message` not to use `Short` on lengthy expressions.

**Edit: Bug apparently fixed in Version 11.1**

`Reduce` no longer produces the warning message given above for `Reduce[eq3 /. {m -> 0, n -> 0}, {A, c1, d, k}, Reals]`, so I could not test

```
    EvaluationData[Reduce[eq3 /. {m -> 0, n -> 0}, {A, c1, d, k}, Reals]]
```

on the exact same case.  I tried a different case, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does seem like a bug and I'll file a report.

In terms of workarounds, it is possible to avoid the application of `Short` by something like

```
Block[{$MessagePrePrint}, 
 ClearSystemCache[]; Reduce[eq3 /. {m -> 0, n -> 0}, Reals] // Simplify]
```

(note `ClearSystemCache[]` has been added to make sure the `Reduce::ztest1` message is always issued)

and the following uses the testing framework to collect the message

```
VerificationTest[ClearSystemCache[]; 
  Reduce[eq3 /. {m -> 0, n -> 0}, Reals] // Simplify;, Null]["ActualMessages"]

(* {HoldForm[Message[Reduce::ztest1, HoldForm[-Log[5381171456512] + 
       Log[((-Sqrt[101])*Log[2] - 10*Sqrt[101]*Log[5] + 
          101*(Log[2] + 10*Log[5] - Log[30100251 - 2278951*Sqrt[101]]) + 
          Sqrt[101]*Log[30100251 - 2278951*Sqrt[101]])^10/((30100251 - 
           2278951*Sqrt[101])*(Log[2] + 10*Log[5] - 
            Log[30100251 - 2278951*Sqrt[101]])^10)]]]]} *)
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce the errors in the question for version 11.1, but `Reduce` no longer produced the particular warning message mentioned in the question.  So, I tried a different case which does produce the warning message, and `EvaluationData` worked well.  Thanks.