# How to store error message from a command into a variable

Tags: warning-messages

I am inserting data into server using `SQLInsert`. I want to store the error messages i encounter when data is not inserted. Apparently the error output is different from function output how do i store the error output rather than the function output `$Failed`.

Comment: Are `$MessageList` or `MessageList` any use to you?

Comment: The complete error is: `JDBC::error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`. While `MessageList[-1]` produces `{JDBC::error}` and `$MessageList` gives `{}`. So nope.

Comment: Question [134698](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134698/1063) and the link it contains may be of help.

Comment: You will like my [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138699/21532). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my comment above more concrete, question [134698](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134698/1063) gives the basic process for capturing the error messages as strings.  For instance, the two error messages from

```
NDSolve[k y[x] + (y''[x] == 0, y, x]
```

can be captured by

```
t = "MessagesText" /. EvaluationData[NDSolve[k y[x] + (y''[x] == 0, y, x]];

t
(* {"NDSolve::ndlim : Range specification x is not of the form {x, xend} or 
        {x, xmin, xmax}.", 
    "NDSolve::ndnco : The number of constraints (0) (initial conditions) is not equal to 
         the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete 
         variables (2)."} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for my case as well.